# SQL : nested query with only one line per criteria (first?)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having difficulties with a simple query.

Here is my table :

```
DIA  PALE POWER  COST
8     7     82   335    
8     7     85   335  <-- 
8     7     96   335  <--
8     8    120   345
9     7    110   324
```

And here is my goal : Selecting values which have the minium cost per different DIA and PALE. 
   BUT when the cost are the same, return only the lowest POWER.

```
DIA  PALE POWER  COST
8     7     82   335
8     8    120   345
9     7    110   324
```

I have the begining of the query but I'm missing the part which does somethings like FIRST( MIN( POWER))

```
Select *
From Table1 T1
WHERE [cost] = (Select min([cost])
             From Table1
             Where dia = T1.dia AND pale = T1.pale)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciate.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subquery to rank the rows in order of cost and power (cost first, being most important) and pick just the rows ranked first per dia/pale group;

```
SELECT DIA PALE, POWER, COST
FROM (
  SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DIA, PALE ORDER BY COST, POWER) rank
  FROM Table1
) q
WHERE rank=1
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c1c3e/1)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this just a simple group by

```
SELECT DIA, PALE, MIN(POWER), COST
FROM From Table1 T1
WHERE [cost] = (Select min([cost])
         From Table1
         Where dia = T1.dia AND pale = T1.pale)
GROUP BY DIA, PALE, COST
```

Comment: Yes that works on the data given above but I've actually more fields that I shall return like SPEED, ... . So I wonder if the GROUP BY is the solution.